# How to setup cron job for a codeigniter script on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

Hi I am trying to setup cron job for a script on server using cpanel however I have never done this and it would really help if someone can guide me.

Script Path: /home/name/public_html/application/modules/stockupdate/controllers/stockupdate.php

I need to run this script every hour I have read tutorials and I have tried to to use following commands:

```
1) php /home/name/public_html/index.php stockupdate 
2)/home/name/public_html/application/modules/stockupdate/controllers/stockupdate.php
```

First one sends the following error:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR</p>
<p>Filename: core/Input.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 351</p>

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/name/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 689</p>

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/name/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/url_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 542</p>
```

The second command send me error that access denied. I would really appreciate if someone can guide me to create cron job please. Thank you

stockupdate.php

```
<?php
class StockUpdate extends Backend_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('ftp');
        $this->load->library('csvimport');
        $this->load->model('stock_update_model');
        ini_set('memory_limit', '3000M');
        set_time_limit(0); 
    }

    function index()
    {
        if ($this->input->is_cli_request())
        {
            $this->stock_update_model->truncate_stock();
            $this->update_stock();
        }
    }

    public function update_stock()
    {
        $ftpServer = "server";
        $ftpUser = "username";
        $ftpPassword = "password";

        $ftp_server = $ftpServer;
        $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
        $ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftpUser, $ftpPassword ); 

        if(!$ftp_conn) 
            die("A connection to $ftpServer couldn't be established"); 
        else if(!$ftp_login) 
            die("Your login credentials were rejected"); 
        else
        {
            $stock_file = "/home/name/files/uploads/stock.CSV";

            $server_file = "/stock.CSV"; 

            if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $stock_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) 
            {
                if (($handle = fopen($stock_file, "r")) !== FALSE) 
                {
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) 
                    {
                        $product_code = $data[0];
                                $stock = $data[1];


                                $this->stock_update_model->update_stock($product_code, $stock); 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                    unlink($stock_file);
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Error reading stock file.\n";
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "There was a problem\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should show us your controller file `stockupdate.php`

Comment: Thank you for your reply give me a minute and I will add that in.

Comment: Try to set cron job by application url. eg 'http://localhost/app_name/controller_name/function_name'

Comment: cron job don't work bcz CI required system files to execute and system file path is relative defined. So try by full url it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `/usr/local/bin/php` instead of `php` to get codeigniter to pick up on the URI segments.

so try this if it works

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/name/public_html/index.php stockupdate index`

Answer (score 3):

I used this commend

```
/usr/bin/curl http://example.com/controller/method
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put `ob_start()` in your config file to remove the last two errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work.

```
php /full-path-to-cron-file/cron.php /test/index
```

Reference [http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/]

Comment: Try this http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/ his will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html you should get the controller class name and the method name and use them to build the CLI command like this:

```
php <path to your CI index.php> <name of the controller class> <name of the function> <optional arguments>
```

so for your code:

```
php /home/name/public_html/index.php stockupdate stock_update
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -t=1 https:// codeginter.com/controller/method
```

Set `t` for the number of attempts.